# Where are Kafka consumer properties set in an SCDF context?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to work myself around a `CommitFailedException` by tinkering with `max.poll.interval.ms`, `session.timeout.ms` and `heartbeat.interval.ms`. I have tried changing these values in the `application.properties` file, but when the app is deployed in an SCDF context, the values I set here are overridden somewhere else. When running the app locally as a stand-alone Spring Boot app, the property values are set to the same as specified in the `application.properties` file.

The dataflow-kafka container is based on the image `confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.2.1`

Where do I tweak Kafka consumer properties in an SCDF context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `max.poll.interval.ms`, `session.timeout.ms` and `heartbeat.interval.ms` appear to be Kafka's consumer configuration.

If you intend to use and override them in your Spring Cloud Stream consumer, you'd have to `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.configuration.foo=bar` notation.

In this example, where `foo` could be `max.poll.interval.ms` and `bar` would be its value: `300000`. For more details, see [ref. guide](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties).

Once when you have all the desired consumer properties defined in this pattern, you can test the application locally via `java -jar`. You can then assure when deployed from SCDF; it would run the same way, as well. Nothing should get overridden.